# Typos and other errors on the site

Tags: bug, status-completed

I've noticed that we have some typos and other errors in the copy on our site.  I don't know what to do when I do see such errors.  For the record, it's not that I'm looking or mistakes, but I just caught two in the process of commenting on one question.

For example, on the [Tour page](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour):

> Graphic Design Stack Exchange is a question and answer for Graphic Design professionals...

A question and answer what? Appears to be missing the word "forum"

I also noticed on the ["on-topic" page](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), in the Font-ID paragraph:

> Those questions area weird fit for your Q&A model, and these rules keep 'em fitting and answerable.

"area" = "are a" and I think "your" should be "our"

I know this may be a bit trivial of me, but I noticed these two things immediately and I wasn't even trying to look.

I don't claim to be an expert in copywriting or editing and by no means am I trying to step on toes, I'm just wondering what to do when I see things like this on the site.

I have a suspicion that if I *were* to look I could find more.  Maybe some of you even have some that you've stumbled across.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed. Thank you for bringing it to our attention.